# Fixing types in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, types

I have a method that is consuming data from an external API:

```
public async getStatus(id: string): Promise<APIRes | undefined> {
    try {
        const result = await getRequest(`${this.URL}/endpoint/${id}`)
        const response: APIRes = result.data

        return response
    } catch (err) {
        errorHandler(err)
    }
}
```

The interface for APIRes looks like:

```
export interface APIRes{
version: string,
status: string,
uuid: string,
time: string
```

}

The issue is when I try to call getStatus from another method:

```
public async getListOfResults(id: string) {
        try {

            const getStatus = await this.getStatus(id)
            if (getStatus.status === 'Queue' || getStatus.status === 'Progr') {
                ...//MORE CODE
            }

            const result = await getRequest(`${this.URL}/endpoint/${id}/result`)

            return result.data
        } catch (err) {
            errorHandler(err)
        }
    }
```

I get `Object is possibly undefined` on getStatus.status. Now I understand why that happens (as the getStatus method could return undefined) but not sure how to best fix without adding the `nostrict` flag.

If I remove the `<| undefined>` in the return type for `getStatus` I get

```
Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.ts(2366)`
```

If I try to change it from undefined to void I still get an error on `getStatus.status`

Comment: what do you want to happen at runtime if `await this.getStatus(id)` produces `undefined`?

Comment: I would expect that to produce an error right

Comment: Well then how about after `const getStatus = ...` and before `if (getStatus.status ...` you just write `if (!getStatus) throw new Error("THE WORLD HAS ENDED");` or something, so that the compiler knows that `getStatus` will definitely be defined.

Comment: You are saying that it returns either a promise with type of APIRes or a promise of undefined? `Promise<APIRes | undefined>` I think what you mean is that it either returns a Promise of type APIRes or it just returns undefined, right?

Comment: You should consider making the code here a true [mcve] that can be dropped into any IDE where the only error is the one you're asking about.  Then someone can know they've answered the question by making sure the example code works as desired.  Good luck!

Comment: You should consider rethrowing the error in `getStatus`; that way, you don't have to define behavior for the weird `undefined` result if there was an error; just let the error bubble up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach makes things more difficult on you than you need things to be. If `getStatus` gets an error, do you *want* it to resolve to `undefined`? If so, then everything that calls it will have to check for that undefined. Why not just let the callers look for thrown errors instead? Simply let the error bubble, or do your error handler and re-throw:

```
public async getStatus(id: string): Promise<APIRes> {
    try {
        const result = await getRequest(`${this.URL}/endpoint/${id}`)
        const response: APIRes = result.data

        return response
    } catch (err) {
        errorHandler(err)
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Now, this will *only* resolve to an `APIRes` and you don't have to handle the case of `undefined`. You just need to make sure something catches the error.

Comment: this seems like a better approach!

Comment: My errorHandler method is already doing something like throw new Error(`there was an error with your req`). If I add the extra `throw err` would that mean it throws twice?

Comment: What's the type of `errorHandler`? Unless it's type `never`, TypeScript may not know that calling it always throws.

Comment: To answer your question, though, if `errorHandler` already throws, then your `throw err;` line won't be reached, so it won't throw twice. If TS isn't smart enough to figure out what `errorHandler` is doing, adding the extra throw statement wouldn't hurt and would be an effective workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You see this error most likely because you set TypeScript to `strict` mode in your tsconfig. This enables another flag `strictNullChecks` which in turn forces the types `any` and `undefined` to only be assignable to themselves, as you can read up [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

In your code, the signature of getStatus is `public async getStatus(id: string): Promise<APIRes | undefined>`, so the returned type can be a `Promise<undefined>`, which means you have to check for it **not** to be undefined.

```
public async getListOfResults(id: string) {
        try {

            const getStatus = await this.getStatus(id)
            if (getStatus // Check if getStatus is NOT undefined before accessing it's properties (so it can only be Promise<APIRes>)
                && (getStatus.status === 'Queue' || getStatus.status === 'Progr')) {
                ...//MORE CODE
            }

            const result = await getRequest(`${this.URL}/endpoint/${id}/result`)

            return result.data
        } catch (err) {
            errorHandler(err)
        }
    }
```